# Docking 2 rich text boxes

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a text editor and I have 2 rich text boxes. I am uses the 1st rich text box as a number like and setting its Enabled property to false. Then the second text box is going next to it

I have currently set the dock of the first text box to left and the second one to fill. But the 2nd one keeps taking up the whole tabpage? And going slightly more left towards the number line and its hidden under there a little bit. Here is my create new document void I have... T2 is the number line and T is the default text box they will type into.

```
TabPage t = new TabPage("new " + getNumber());
tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t);
tabControl1.SelectedTab = t;
RichTextBox T2 = new RichTextBox();
t.Controls.Add(T2);
T2.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
T2.Enabled = false;

RichTextBox T = new RichTextBox();
t.Controls.Add(T);
T.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
T.Font = new Font("Microsoft San Serif", 11);
Random R = new Random();
int RandomNumberHere = R.Next(1000, 100000);
T.Text = "Welcome, type your text...";
T.Select();
```

Comment: [winforms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Forms), right?

Comment: is that name for real?

Comment: Dock.Fill fills. It doesn't fill the rest it fills all. Eithe use anchors or code your resize event. Be clear as to what you want. You certainly didn't tell us..

Comment: @TaW that is not true... `Dock.Fill` fills the available space minus the other docked controls. You just need a specific order (z-order) of elements to achieve what you want. I think the question was very specific and the OP was doing it the right way (just in not the right order). Using anchors or resizing events is the wrong way to go for this and a source of GREAT pain should the form ever change afterwards.

Comment: [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.dockstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396):  _If Fill is selected, all four sides of the control are resized to match the containing control's edges._ - Your code needs using `BringToFront`, which clearly shows that the cotrols do not sit side by side but overlap, hardly useful for RTBs, imo..And not what the OP wants. What he __still has not told us__ is : What shall happen when the user resizes the container, i.e:How shall the sizes change??

Comment: To me, taking the description of the problem (one RTB for line numbers and another for the text) it's obvious that the `Fill` one should take the remaining space (and the problem is that, since it's added last, takes the whole parent space, so they overlap), which is simply a matter of changing the z-order. If you align both to left (as in your answer), unless you set and change the width every time (and take into account the remaining space, should you add any new control), it won't fill the parent: it's also a maintenance hell: that's precisely what docking came to avoid.

Comment: To be clear: I don't endorse doing such an interface (using a RTB for line numbers and a different one for text) and I'd rather have a single control with a property, but that's not the point of the question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you define your `fill-docked` text box at the end of the control list... winforms likes the fill-docked elements first in the list.

Easily solved:

```
RichTextBox T = new RichTextBox();
t.Controls.Add(T);
T.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
T.Font = new Font("Microsoft San Serif", 11);
// Add this line
T.BringToFront();
```

Or you could also do `T2.SendToBack();` **after** `T` is added to the controls collection.

Or you could simply create (and add to `t.Controls`), the fill-docked textbox first, and the left-docked textbox second.

Either way works

By the way, try to name your variables correctly. `t`, `T`, `T2` are just not good names

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
t.Controls.Add(T2);
t.Controls.Add(T);

t.Controls.SetChildIndex(T, 1);
t.Controls.SetChildIndex(T2, 0);

t.PerformLayout();  // needed after SetChildIndex!

T2.Dock = DockStyle.Left;    
T.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
```

If you want your boxes to grow with the `TabPage` here is one way to do it:

```
private void t_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   // assuming you want the two RTBs to fill the TabPage
   // if you want something else, best add an anchored container panel
   // and use its resize event instead
   T2.Width = t.Width / 4;
   T.Width = t.Width / 4;
}
```

And yes, `t, T and T2` are really bad names!

Answer (score -1):

There's a few things going on:

Fill does just that; it Fills the entirety of the PARENT control. Whether anything else is there or not.

Your other text box will be hidden until it is set to Enabled.

What you Might? be looking for is a way to have the text box size itself based on the size of the tab page being created:

```
    {

        TabPage t = new TabPage("new " + 1);
        tabControl1.TabPages.Add(t);
        tabControl1.SelectedTab = t;
        RichTextBox T2 = new RichTextBox();
        t.Controls.Add(T2);
        T2.Dock = DockStyle.Left;
        T2.Enabled = true ;

        RichTextBox T = new RichTextBox();
        t.Controls.Add(T);
        T2.Dock = DockStyle.Right;
        var AdjustedSize = T2.Size;
        AdjustedSize.Width = t.Size.Width * 2 / 3;
        T2.Size = AdjustedSize;
        T.Font = new Font("Microsoft San Serif", 11);
        Random R = new Random();
        int RandomNumberHere = R.Next(1000, 100000);
        T.Text = "Welcome, type your text...";
        T.Select();

    }
```